# Do jigsaws differ in the depth that they can cut (with the same blade)?

Tags: cutting, saw

I have a need to cut accurate shapes (including interior cuts) in some 4" thick polyethylene foam.  Normally I would use a hot knife for this - but this thick and heavy of a material is right at the limit of what my knife can cut, even at its maximum temperature setting it takes a large amount of sideways force to get it to cut, and it's killing my wrist.

Looking for possible alternatives, I found a specialty jigsaw blade intended for cutting foam.  It claims to have a 5" working length - but they are apparently using a definition of "working length" that means something other than "working length", because it comes about a quarter of an inch short of cutting all the way through this 4" foam.  (The picture shows the jigsaw sitting on top of a piece of the foam, with the blade at maximum extension.)

[image]

I don't know whether this is just deceptive advertising, or due to the design of the particular jigsaw I have.  It certainly looks like there's enough slack in the design that the chuck and roller could be moved down at least a quarter inch.  So my question is: is it possible that a different jigsaw would give me enough extension of the blade to cut all the way through?  If so, what is this feature called, so I can shop for it?

Comment: This is an interesting question. I've always just purchased a longer blade (I've got 8-10" long jig-saw blades!) when needing a deeper cut. It seems this isn't an option for you, though. It may just be "creative" marketing at work. I'm interested to see what others have to say.

Comment: Different makes of jig saws might have different height between base and motor/plunger.  Yours looks higher than my old basic saw.